# How can I get a specific data in Firebase (Kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I need to retrieve the "administrator" value from Firebase
[image: the Firebase database]

This is the code I use:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/restaurants/$restaurantUID/administrator")
            .get().addOnSuccessListener {

            Log.d("key", it.toString())
        }
```

The result in the log is this though:
2022-09-05 17:07:32.271 2885-2885/com.example.menuapp D/key: DataSnapshot { key = administrator, value = null }

How can I get the actual value for "administrator" and not a null?

Comment: If you try to log the value of `restaurantUID`, what's the output?

Answer (score 1):

According to your last comment, I see that value of `restaurantUID` is:

```
eefef966-f227-45e8-b875-f568b87ee1fc
```

Which is totally different than the one in the database. The one in the database strats with "c20f02b0-...", hence that null for the value of `administrator` filed. If you want to get the correct value, then always make sure you're reading the data on the correct path:

```
val restaurantUID = "eefef966-f227-45e8-b875-f568b87ee1fc"
val db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val adminRef = db.child("restaurants/$restaurantUID/administrator")
adminRef.get().addOnSuccessListener {
    Log.d("key", it.toString())
}
```

Comment: It still remains null the value of `administrator`

Comment: Is `restaurants` a direct child of your root?

Comment: yes, `restaurants` is a direct child

Comment: And if you try to use `Log.d("key", it.getValue<String>())`?

Comment: Hey Lorenz. Have you solved the issue? Can I help you with other information?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this -**

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/restaurants/$restaurantUID").orderByChild("administrator").equalTo(“Alr6tf3nzTNTXbx53ysbcAxcM643”).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
    System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getKey());
  }
});
```